# Postgresql, references to unique constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.4 and have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE user_cars (
    user_id SERIAL REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    car CHARACTER VARYING(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT test UNIQUE (user_id, car)
);
```

The table allows a user to have multiple cars, but only use the car name once. But other users may have the same car name.

I would like to have another table with references to the unique constraint `test`, and have tried stuff like:

```
CREATE TABLE mappings (
    other_id CHARACTER(9) REFERENCES other (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    user_cars  REFERENCES user_cards (test) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

But that fails "obviously". I would like to make sure that `other_id` only have a single references to a `user_car` entry.

So to explain, how can I in table `mappings` have a references to `test` from table `user_cars`.
This is the thing that fails currently:

```
    user_cars  REFERENCES user_cards (test) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use composite foreign key references, if you can avoid it.  Just add a unique id to the table:

```
CREATE TABLE user_cars (
    user_car_id serial primary key,
    user_id int REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    car CHARACTER VARYING(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT test UNIQUE (user_id, car)
);
```

Then mappings is simply:

```
CREATE TABLE mappings (
    mapping_id serial primary key,
    user_car_id int references user_cars(user_car_id) on delete cascade,
    other_id CHARACTER(9) REFERENCES other (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
);
```

Comment: Don't think I quite understand. The mappings table second column should refer to the unique combination of `user_id` and `car`, not just one of the columns.

Comment: I cannot make the `user_car_id` a primay key, because then other users wouldn't be able to use that name.

Comment: Wait, you are correct. Missing the fact that you made a new primary key - of course. Simple. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If `car` should be unique, add `UNIQUE` constrain only on `car` column.
If `user` should be unique, add `UNIQUE` constrain only on `user` column.

If you add `UNIQUE` constrain on combination, then there will be duplicate values in the table.

UPDATE:
You can add multiple constraints on single column. With `Foreign key` add `UNIQUE` constraint as well on `user_cars` column in `mapping` table.

Comment: I don't mind that `user` has several entries for `car`, but `user` cannot have multiple entries with same `car` name. Therefor the constraint on `user_id` and `car`. This seems to work fine.
My problem is in the `mappings` table and how I can reference to that `unique` `constraint`.